# Unable to build Rails with Webpack on Github Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm trying to build Ruby on Rails with Webpack on Github Actions my yml config looks like this:

```
name: CI
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      db:
        image: postgres:11
        ports: ['5432:5432']
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 2.6.x
      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 10.13.0
      - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
        with:
          cmd: install
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev postgresql-client
          gem install bundler
          yarn install
      - name: Bundle install
        run: bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
      - name: Rubocop check
        run: bundle exec rubocop
      - name: Brakerman check
        run: bundle exec brakeman
      - name: Webpack compilation
        run: NODE_ENV=test bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
      - name: Build and run tests
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/test
          RAILS_ENV: test
          RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}
        run: |
          bundle exec rails db:prepare
          bundle exec rspec
```

I have a problem with `NODE_ENV=test bundle exec rails webpacker:compile` step, it returns following error:

```
Run NODE_ENV=test bundle exec rails webpacker:compile

Compiling…

Compilation failed:


##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

How can I fix that?

EDIT:

Here is the log from webpack:
https://gist.github.com/MatUrbanski/bca6f191694dea60437244c1bcb5b653

Comment: Try setting `webpack_compile_output: true` in `webpacker.yml` to see if you get more information about the error.

Comment: @peterevans I added webpack logs to my question.

Comment: Is webpacker being installed? What does `which webpack` return before `webpacker:compile`? Is this a test app? Do you have a repository?

Comment: After looking at the log from webpack I found the following question. Do any of the solutions there help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652404/issue-using-node-sass-after-updating-nodejs